# How to change timeout the query

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

For queries with many records, I have the timeout issue. How can I change the query timeout?

I tried changing the timeout connection this way, but it does not work:

**connection.ConnectionTimeout = 60; // not working (ready)**

Class:

```
public abstract class RepositoryBase<TEntity> : IRepositoryBase<TEntity>, IDisposable where TEntity : class
{
    protected SqlConnection _connection;
    protected string _connectionString;

    public RepositoryBase(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            connection.ConnectionTimeout = 60; // not working (ready)
            connection.Open();

        _connection = connection;
    }

    public List<T> GetEntitiesByQuery<T>(string Query)
    {
        using (var connection = _connection)
        {
            try
            {
                var entities = connection.Query<T>(Query);
                return entities.ToList();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know how long the query does take to run?

Comment: About 1 minute, but timeout is 30 seconds

Comment: "For queries with many records" - amount of records in a database should not be your bottleneck in a query. If that happens, it means there's a problem somewhere else. What you're doing here, increasing the timeout, is going to fix your problem, but you're putting a dirty band-aid over a bigger problem. Look at your query again, look at the execution plan, check indexes, etc.

Comment: I'm doing a simple query (SELECT FIELD1,FIELD2,FIELD3 FROM TABLE), but the query return is 300k records. 
When the query exceeds 30 seconds, the timeout

Comment: In that case you should use commandtimeout instead of connectiontimeout

Comment: Why `entity-framework` tag? Looks like you are using different (micro)ORM?

Comment: Roshan , I can not return an object in SqlCommand! :/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to set the [`CommandTimeout`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.idbcommand.commandtimeout?view=netframework-4.7.2) property:

> The time (in seconds) to wait for the command to execute. The default value is 30 seconds.

How do you set it depends on the data access technology used.

For plain ADO.NET:

```
IDbCommand cmd = ...;
cmd.CommandTimeout = 120; // 2 min
```

For EF6:

```
DbContext db = ...;
db.Database.CommandTimeout = 120; // 2 min
```

But looks like you are using [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper). The `Query<T>` method used has currently the following signature:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Query<T>(
    this IDbConnection cnn,
    string sql,
    object param = null,
    IDbTransaction transaction = null,
    bool buffered = true,
    int? commandTimeout = null,
    CommandType? commandType = null
)
```

As you can see, a lot of *optional* parameters, and one of them is the `commandTimeout` you need. So you can use something like this:

```
var entities = connection.Query<T>(Query, commandTimeout: 120);
```

Or you can set the default timeout for all queries:

```
SqlMapper.Settings.CommandTimeout = 120; // 2 min
```

Comment: I used "var entities = connection.Query<T>(Query, commandTimeout: 120);"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like query is taking more than 60sec. Set it as 0 (infinite) and check.

```
connection.ConnectionTimeout = 0;
```

Most accepted method of doing this is through the CommandTimeout property of the SqlCommand object.

Comment: I read about it but did not get the return from the list. (List<T>)

Answer (score 0):

If timeout is read-only it mean you are already connected to database other way you can change it .
try set the time out in a connection string maybee it help organise code better.

```
 <connectionStrings>  
    <... connectionString="User ID=sa;Password=XXXXX;Initial Catalog=qualitaBorri;Data Source=PC_NAME\SQLEXPRESS;Connection Timeout=60"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: I've tried it this way, but this timeout is the connection time of the bank and not the query time

Comment: i'm not sure but you should check server side if your query run localy against sqlserver. sqlserver has a timeout himself so no mater your code if your query is considered too long by the server. so it useless persiste in this direction you have prolly to think different way to get your data for exemple how many row you call realy? can you think of a way to optimise this? can you use a stored procedure or paging your call?